# how update the variable on button click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

could you please tell me how to update the variable on button click ?Actually I have three variable first ,lastname and fullname .on Button click I change lastname But it not reflect on model ? Could I used digest or watch function ?

```
var loginCntrl=function($scope){
  $scope.testClick =function(){
    alert('sss');
    $scope.lastname="kumar";
     $scope.watch(function($scope){
       return $scope.name;
     }, function($scope){
       return $scope.name;
     })

  }

$scope.name="naveen";
$scope.lastname="sharam";
$scope.fullname=$scope.name+$scope.lastname;
}
```

Comment: you don't need `$watch`

Comment: how i will acheive that updated value ..

Comment: there's no model in your code...

Comment: It's $scope.$watch, and the $watch handler is not injectible, so passing in $scope does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you click handler to following

```
$scope.testClick =function(){
        alert('sss');
        $scope.lastname="kumar";
        $scope.fullname=$scope.name+$scope.lastname;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button ng-click="lastName='jonathan'">Test</button>
```

If you want to change only one parameter, you can change the variable on click like **ng-click="lastName='jonathan'** , if you want to manipulate multiple variables, then call a function as below,

function call:

**ng-click="changeValues()"**

```
$scope.changeValues=function(){
  $scope.lastName="Jonathan";
  //Other code comes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey find the jsfiddle its simple you dont need to use $watch just need to update the lastname in `$scope.lastname` :

```
"http://jsfiddle.net/c9fru8ky/"
```